# How to define a trigger in MYSQL to prevent certain values INSERTed into a table?

Tags: mysql

Do I need to use the REVOKE command for this? How exactly would I do it?

Example: I have a table called 'users' with only one column called 'username'. Let's say I want to block a user called 'username1'. How do I block it so it's not possible to add him with an INSERT command? (but I want all other values possible to add using INSERT).

Thanks!

Comment: I need to block more than one value like this (10-20). Thanks

Comment: Create a table of blacklisted names. Have your insert check the blacklist before inserting into the username.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.username = 'username1' OR NEW.username = 'username2' THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Wrong values for username';
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```